# dbcontext был уже удален EF в с#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

При использование в с# при технологии entity framework подход database first возникает проблема при подключение к objectdatasource модели данных возникает проблема  с выводом в gridview и на экран выводится ошибка:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed error

---

перефразирую свой вопрос) как подключать модель данных созданную с помощью entity framework к элементу работы с бд objectdatasource?

Comment: На какой из представленных строчек кода возникает ошибка?

Comment: ошибка возникает когда возвращаются данные из бд